# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tram' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webflow

I used webflow. Now there is a conflict when loading webflow.js.

What is the reason? How to fix?

http://s90009lu.beget.tech/teete/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx8sz.png

Comment: please provide some snippets of code. So it can give a solution to the question.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS The page loads a full file webflow.js. It contains too much code, so I can't paste it here.

Comment: Hi Tony, please try if you can find the cause of the issue. Remove any bits of code that don't cause any issues. Also, it looks like the website uses some kind of processing to generate webflow.js. Debuggein this kind of code is hard. Try to work with the raw sources instead.

Comment: @Tonystark please see this solution, it might help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325596/10453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So even though the provided information is minimal i'm going to give it a shot:

As there is no actual sourcecode (code given seems to be packaged) i'm assuming this is some kind of a plugin. Which leads me to believe that this might not be the only case. Let just look at the exact error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tram' of undefined

What this means is dat the browser tries to ook for a property called "tram" in an undefined variable. As undefined is something that is... wel... undefined. There can't be any properties. This produces this error.

A good practice to start of with some context might be just using a Google search of the exact problem. Let's search for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tram' of undefined".

Some results points up, al indicating stuff with webflow. Let's look at this result: https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-trigger-webflow-js-slider/11268.

The third post states that adding the line `var $ = jQuery;` got the user a step further. This provides some very clear context.

`var $ = jQuery;` assigns `$` refer to the place in memory of the variable `jQuery`, a popular library. This basically creates an alias. Remarkable: `$` tends to be a default (shipped) alias of `jQuery`. Something is off here.

Opening the browser (Chrome) developer tools shows the error shown in the screenshot. We can get some more precise information here by utilizing the debugger.

- Open the devtools.
- Click on a link to webflow.js to open it the sources tab.
- Check the break on exceptions button (shaped like a stop sign).
- Use the "{}" on the lower left to format the code.
- Reload the page.

We can now see the code stop a certain point where it looks for `tram`. Just in front of that we see that it's looking in a newly created alias for window.$ (!).

The last thing makes to believe that indeed, jQuery is not properly installed. Either by the plugin or by a conflict in other modules. The suggested `var $ = jQuery;` line might work to fix this, but please keep in mind that jQuery should be made available first for this to work.

This last thing requires it to be bundled correctly or installed using a different method. As we don't know your exact situation you might need to look into this yourself.

Comment: It really helped to get rid of the conflict, but it did not solve the problem. 
webflow.js contains scrollintoview animations but for some reason animations are missing. Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: I jumped to conclusions. This did not help, unfortunately

Comment: @Tonystark please checkout this solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325596/10453 and see my comment beneath about how my using it solved a problem I had where I saw that `tram` error like you.